# Pass database name in batch file sql server

Tags: sql-server, batch-file

Here is my SQL code. I have tried it 2 ways and both are giving me the error at the database name

> incorrect syntax near 'Intake_Bak_09_04_15_07_15'

Method 1

```
INSERT INTO Inspectors (InspectorId, FirstName, LastName, UserName, ReplicationId) 
   SELECT 
       InspectorId, FirstName, LastName, UserName, ReplicationId 
   FROM N'$(oldDBName)'.dbo.Inspectors

INSERT INTO MachineSettings (Name, Value) 
    SELECT Name, Value 
    FROM N'$(oldDBName)'.dbo.MachineSettings 
    WHERE Name = 'MachineId'
```

Method 2

```
DECLARE @InsSql VARCHAR(500), @MacSql   VARCHAR(500)

SET @InsSql = 'INSERT INTO Inspectors (InspectorId, FirstName, LastName, UserName, ReplicationId) SELECT InspectorId, FirstName, LastName, UserName, ReplicationId FROM N['$(oldDBName)'].dbo.Inspectors'

PRINT @InsSql

EXEC (@InsSql)

SET @MacSql = 'INSERT INTO MachineSettings (Name, Value) SELECT Name, Value FROM N['$(oldDBName)'].dbo.MachineSettings WHERE Name = ''MachineId'''

PRINT @MacSql

EXEC (@MacSql)
```

Here is the SQLCMD I am using

```
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%i in ("%date%") do (
     set dow=%%i
     set month=%%j
     set day=%%k
     set year=%%l
   )
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=: " %%i in ("%time%") do (
     set hour=%%i
     set min=%%j
     set sec=%%k
   )

SQLCMD -S . -d Intake -i TransferSQL.Sql -b -v oldDBName=Intake_Bak_%month%_%day%_%year%_%hour%_%min%
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: the dbname cannot be a varchar. try to use `[$(oldDBName)]` instead of `N['$(oldDBName)']`

Comment: Awesome, it worked. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the syntax that worked, Thanks to Paolo

```
INSERT INTO Inspectors (InspectorId, FirstName, LastName, UserName, ReplicationId) SELECT InspectorId, FirstName, LastName, UserName, ReplicationId FROM [$(oldDBName)].dbo.Inspectors
INSERT INTO MachineSettings (Name, Value) SELECT Name, Value FROM [$(oldDBName)].dbo.MachineSettings WHERE Name = 'MachineId'
```